# Guide rails display sql below results

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

Newbie in rails, i am learning the guide to rails but have an issue :

When i query something, below results i have those lines displayed in the web browser :

```
[#<Post id: 1, title: "julien", text: "errzr", created_at: "2014-02-11 14:22:04", updated_at: "2014-02-11 14:22:04">, #<Post id: 2, title: "albert", text: "einstein", created_at: "2014-02-11 14:24:23", updated_at: "2014-02-11 14:24:23">, #<Post id: 3, title: "julia", text: "roberts", created_at: "2014-02-12 10:40:32", updated_at: "2014-02-12 10:40:32">, #<Post id: 4, title: "ricky", text: "balboa", created_at: "2014-02-12 10:42:28", updated_at: "2014-02-12 10:42:28">]
```

I really don't know how to disable it and to enable it ??

Thank you very much for your help !!

Comment: you might be using `<%=`, you should use `<%` instead when you are doing any manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

Use `<%` instead of `<%=` when you are doing any manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

Anything in your `.erb` file enclosed in `<%= %>` will executed and displayed in the view . if you just want to execute a query there you can just enclose that in `<% %>` which is still a executable instruction but the outcome of that will not be displayed in the view.